# Ubuntu LAMP Virtual Host - Apache 500 Internal Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, lamp

I create a virtual host using virtualhost.sh script (you can find it easily on GitHub), and mapped it to the root of my project folder (Yii2 Project), when I visit my virtual host, I got Apache 500 Internal Error.

Ubuntu LAMP

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the rewrite module wasn't enabled by default when you install LAMP manually, and the `.htaccess` file in the root directory uses RewriteEngine...

Enable rewrite module:
`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Then, you need to restart your Apache:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Done.